# PHP Alternate between commands based on variable

Tags: php

I am trying to build an HTML without having to duplicate code.
Basically I have the option to print or save to file; option will be passed through `$_GET`.

I loop through a csv, so the HTML receive lots of variables.

I thought of having a variable $action;

```
If $action == 'view' then

    echo "<h1>Hello World</h1>";

If $action == 'save' then

    file_put_contents($file,"<h1>Hello World</h1>", FILE_APPEND);
```

I don't like the idea of having to repeat the code, with one section using echo and the other `file_put_contents`.

I know it's completly wrong, only trying to give the idea, is there a way of kind set a variable like this?

```
if ($action == "view") {$start = 'echo'; $end = ';';}
elseif ($action == "save") {$start = 'file_put_contents($file,'; $end = ', FILE_APPEND);';}

$start "<h1>Hello World</h1>" $end
```

Comment: No, that would be completely the wrong approach. You should look into _output buffering_.

Comment: @misorude 'output buffering' gets the job done. Sweet! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is completely wrong, syntax error.

But you can do this:

```
$str = '<h1>Hello World</h1>';

switch ($action) {
    case 'view':
        echo $str;
        break;
    case 'save':
        file_put_contents($file, $str, FILE_APPEND);
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception('Invalid action');
}
```

Comment: If you throw an exception, that really should be caught.

Comment: Thank you! I really liked your idea.

Comment: @Martin Well, all servers can handle uncaught exceptions, I will not include error handlers/error pages to such simple example.